# How to check if `wget` supports a certain feature programmatically?

Tags: wget

Is there a way to programmatically detect if the currently installed wget supports a given feature; for example, IRI support?

I’m asking because I’d like to add these lines to my `.wgetrc`:

```
# Use UTF-8 as the default system encoding
local_encoding = UTF-8
```

But this makes wget unusable if it doesn’t support the `local_encoding` setting.

So, I’d like to conditionally configure this setting, only if wget supports the feature.

In Vim (`.vimrc` files) you can do this using `has()` and `exists()`:

```
if has("autocmd")
  " Define autocommands here
endif
```

How can I do something similar for wget in `.wgetrc`?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot include any extra logic into `.wgetrc`, so using shell initialization as described in enzotib's answer seems to be the only possibility.

Beside of `--help`, you can get the build configuration of GNU’s wget and therefore the enabled features via `--version`:

```
if wget --version | grep -q "+iri"; then 
    # modify ~/.wgetrc
fi
```

In the case you need to test if a feature is also included in busybox’s wget, you need to know that is does not support `--version` and prints instead its "--help" to stderr (not stdout as GNU’s wget).

Answer (score 1):

What about this in some shell initialization script?

```
if wget --help | grep -q "local-encoding"; then 
    # modify ~/.wgetrc
fi
```

Comment: I like it! I’d prefer a solution that keeps all the logic in the `.wgetrc` file itself, but I guess that’s just not possible, then.